# Send a Toast Notification to spscific Windows Account not by WNS

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, toast, wns

I have this situation:

I need to send a notification through Action Center and I know that there are two ways: **API and WNS (Windows Push Notification Service)**.
WNS is not an option for me due all clients Win 10 belong to an internal LAN without Internet access.
I reviewed the API alternative but in our case, certain notification are for certain Windows Accounts; and for that reason I need to send one notification to certain Users.

How you mind the strategy?

Thanks in advance for your help

We have, for now, the constraint all notification must to send through Action Center.

Thanks